# Admob house ads on android apps

Tags: cordova, phonegap, admob, cordova-admob

I am working on an android application using cordova/phonegap. I want to show my own ads to the users. I searched on google and found the admob house ads can solve my problem. But I am not sure whether admob will show other ads or only show my ads. Can someone please tell me about this?

I want to show only my own custom ads and don't want any other ad to be shown.

Thanks

Comment: you can goto Campaign Tab in Admob and create a new campaign. There is option to set Goal where you can set how much impressions your own ads should be shown. Follow this link https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6212567?hl=en to know more

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I read that page you provided, they say "House ad campaigns are cross-promotion campaigns that serve ads to an app using a developer's own inventory for free."

But I want to show not only my other apps ads but ads for some other products  etc. Can you please tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: What you are looking for is Direct Sales or Cross platform sales. When you create a new Campagin in Admob Select Type is house Ad or Direct Sold. Direct sold will allow you to advertise other apps in your app. https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6222913?ctx=tltp&hl=en

Comment: I don't want to advertise other apps but other products like shoe, bicycle etc. Do they allow to do this?

Comment: It looks like you can now use Direct Sold ads to display any type of advertisement. I tried setting 100% impression percentage but other ads are still being displayed...